# BSONObj size error

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections both having more than 15 million entries. I am doing indexing on both the collections and doing find() on both . I am getting the following error
""10334:BSONObj size: 27624158 (0xDE82A501) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: _id: ObjectId('532d4a424a33b081be8a0315')".

How can I resolve this error ? I hv already done database repair but it didnt work.

Comment: MongoDB BSON documents cannot be larger than 16MB, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/, However I don't understand how you could store it in first place. Could you post your sentences against your mongo ?

Comment: The only way to fix this is to actually create a JS script that iterates the whole collection one by one finding the bsonsize method: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous and remove those over 16meg

Comment: @RobertoSánchez in reality a BSON document can be any size it wants, the 16meg rule is nothing more than a limit check in MongoDBs code, totally superficial in reality

Comment: I know, I said "MongoDB BSON documents", I meant "BSON docs _in_ MongoDB"

Comment: @RobertoSánchez ah ok yeah,

Comment: I'm getting this and none of the documents I work with are big at all.